Factorizibility of a morphism of schemes when the continuous image is contained in a closed subscheme.
This seems easy question but raise that for making certainly sure. Let $(f,f^{b}): X\to Y$ ( $ f^{b} : \mathcal{O}_Y \to f_{*}\mathcal{O}_X$ ) be a morphism of schemes. Assume that $f(X) \subseteq V$, where $\iota : V \hookrightarrow Y$ be a closed subscheme of $Y$. Then the factorization of $f$ through $\iota$ is possible? If $V$ is an open subscheme it seems possible and how about the case that $V$ is closed subscheme?

If by $f(X)\subset V$, you mean as sets, then no, it is not necessarily true that $f$ factors through $\iota$. Here is an example: let $X=\coprod_{n\geq 0} \operatorname{Spec} k[x]/(x^n)$, $Y=\operatorname{Spec} k[x]$, and $f$ be the morphism which on each component $\operatorname{Spec} k[x]/(x^n)$ of $X$ is the obvious map $\operatorname{Spec} k[x]/(x^n)\to \operatorname{Spec} k[x]$. The set-theoretic image is just $(x)$, but the smallest closed subscheme through which $f$ factors is actually all of $Y$: the kernel of $\mathcal{O}_Y(Y) = k[x]\to \prod_{n\geq 0} k[x]/(x^n) = \mathcal{O}_X(X)$ is the zero ideal, and a morphism $f:X\to Y$ for an affine scheme $Y$ factors through a closed subscheme $V(I)\subset Y$ iff $I$ is contained in the kernel of the map $\mathcal{O}_Y(Y)\to\mathcal{O}_X(X)$.
The key term for you to use here is the scheme-theoretic image of a morphism. Given an arbitrary morphism $f:X\to Y$ between arbitrary schemes, we define the scheme-theoretic image of $f$ to be the smallest closed subscheme $\iota:Z\to Y$ through which $f$ factors. The above counterexample shows that the scheme-theoretic image may have underlying set which is not simply the closure of the set-theoretic image, but there are two conditions which can establish this result: if either $X$ is reduced (ref Stacks 056B) or $f$ is quasi-compact (ref Stacks 01R8). If $X$ is reduced and $V$ is any subscheme of $Y$ such that $f(X)\subset V$ as sets, then $f$ factors through $\iota$, since the scheme-theoretic image in that case is just the set $\overline{f(X)}$ equipped with the reduced induced structure. If $f$ is quasi-compact but $X$ is not necessarily reduced, you will need to worry about the subscheme structure: consider $X=\operatorname{Spec} k[x]/(x^3)$, $Y=\operatorname{Spec} k[x]$, and $V=\operatorname{Spec} k[x]/(x^2)$ with all of the obvious maps.
If $U\subset Y$ is an open subscheme and $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism of schemes with $f(X)\subset U$ as sets, then $f$ factors through $U$, and this is simple check: the map of topological spaces $g:X\to U$ is just the corestriction of the map of topological spaces $f$, and the morphism of sheaves $\mathcal{O}_Y \to f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ naturally gives to a map $\mathcal{O}_Y \to g_*\mathcal{O}_U$ since $(f_*\mathcal{O}_X)(W)=\mathcal{O}_X(f^{-1}(W))$ and $f^{-1}(W)\subset U$ by assumption, so $\mathcal{O}_X(f^{-1}(W)) = \mathcal{O}_U(f^{-1}(W)) = \mathcal{O}_U(g^{-1}(W))$.

Thanks for kind explanation! Can I ask more about the first paragraph of your answer? 1) Why $\prod_{n\geq 0} k[x]/(x^n) = \mathcal{O}_X(X)$ ? 2) For the final statement in the first paragraph, I think that "the kernel of the map $\mathcal{O}_Y(Y) \to \mathcal{O}_X(X)$ contains $I$ ",  is more correct sentence, instead of " .. is contained in $I$ " . 3) I am trying to understand the "if" direction of the final statement. Even if $X$ is not affine, $f: X\to Y:=\operatorname{Spec}A$ factors through $V(I) \subseteq Y$ if the kernel of the map contains $I$? How to show?

I think that the zeroth of the kernel implies that the map factors through the closed subscheme $Y$ 'only'. Reason for the claim of my own is as follows : 1) Assume that "my proposed correction is true".  2) Fix a closed subscheme $V(I) \subseteq \mathrm{Spec}A$ such that $f :X\to Y$ factors through it in your counter example. 3) Then the zeroth of the kernel and my correction assumption implies that $I=0$. So $V(I)=V(0) = Y$ !. Is there any part that I made mistake? How do you think about this ?

Sorry, it's very late and I have been busy today, the correct statement is that $I$ should be contained in the kernel. Sheaf answer: if a space $X$ has an open cover by disjoint opens $U_i$ and $F$ is a sheaf on $X$, then by the sheaf property we have that $F(X)=\prod F(U_i)$ - any collection of sections on the $U_i$ trivially agree on overlaps.

To explain the containment issue, suppose we think about this on the level of affine schemes. If a map $\operatorname{Spec} B\to \operatorname{Spec} A$ factors through $\operatorname{Spec} A/I$, then the ring homomorphism $A\to B$ factors as $A\to A/I \to B$, which occurs when $I\subset \ker(A\to B)$: if there is an element of $I$ which is not in the kernel, then we couldn't have a map $A/I\to B$ which factors $A\to B$, since something equal to $0$ in $A/I$ would be going to something nonzero in $B$; when $I\subset\ker(A\to B)$, then we have a factorization by the first isomorphism theorem.

To see the answer about factorization even when $X$ is not affine, recall that maps from a scheme $X$ to an affine scheme $\operatorname{Spec} A$ are in bijection with ring maps $A \to \mathcal{O}_X(X)$ (ref). So if a map $X\to\operatorname{Spec} A$ factors through $\operatorname{Spec} A/I$, then the map $A\to \mathcal{O}_X(X)$ factors as $A\to A/I \to \mathcal{O}_X(X)$ which happens only if $I$ is contained in the kernel, like in the above comment.

O.K. I think that I checked your final comment already. Thanks. And, remaining doubts is, I don't undersatnd the 'if'-direction of the final statement in the first paragraph of your answer, although it seems that it doesn't need for your counter example. If $X$ is affine it ( if-direction ) is possible but if not, I still don't reach to satisfactory proof. Perhaps, it does not work in general..

You can run a similar argument to my last comment. If $A\to\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ factors as $A\to A/I\to\mathcal{O}_X(X)$, then the map $A/I\to \mathcal{O}_X(X)$ is equivalent to a morphism $X\to\operatorname{Spec} A/I$ which when post-composed with the standard inclusion $\operatorname{Spec} A/I \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ gives the same map $A\to \mathcal{O}_X(X)$ and hence the same morphism of schemes $X\to\operatorname{Spec} A$, showing $X\to \operatorname{Spec} A$ factors through $V(I)$.

O.K. Brilliance. I understand your overall strategy. To check each part your argument, it needs some calculation, perhaps refering concrete construction in  https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01I1.  ( Or..I think there is a possibility that, if we note something, then we can naturally figure it out, possibly avoiding using the concrete construction.. ) Anyway, thank you.

The concrete construction is not so difficult and it's something I would expect to prove early on in an algebraic geometry course, definitely before thinking about scheme-theoretic image. For instance, this is Hartshorne exercise II.2.4, the fourth exercise after seeing the definition of a scheme, or Vakil 7.3.G (in the latest notes) in just the third section during the chapter where one is learning what a morphism of schemes is.

O.K. I fianlly got it. Through trying to prove, I think that we don't need such a concrete construction, altough I can figure out it for $X$ is scheme. We just note that $g^{b}_{(\mathrm{Spec}(A/I))} = \bar{\varphi} : A/I \to \mathcal{O}_X(X)$ ( $ (g, g^{b}) $ corresponds to $\bar{\varphi} : A/I \to \mathcal{O}_X(X)$ ) and by using the notion of the composition of morphisms of schemes. Thank you for teaching me method using https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01I1 :)
